# Application defined or object defined error in VBA in passing parameter to a function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pass a worksheet variable to a function as its parameter. Here is the code

```
Public varcol as integer

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim wrk as WorkSheet
If Range("A1") = "a" then
Set wrk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1")
Call fun(wrk)
End If
End Sub

Function fun(ByVal wrk As Worksheet) As Double

Dim b As Integer
Dim w As Double
w = wrk.Cells(b, varcol).Value                  'Line with the error
For b = 4 To 12

   c = watt - w

   If c < 1 Then

   ah = Sheets("wrk").Cells(b, varcol - 1)

   End If

Next b

End Function
```

Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: `w = wrk.Cells(b, varcol).Value` here `b` is `0` since you haven't initialize it. Also don't see where have you initialized `varcol`

Comment: @simoco Thanks actually I did not initialized `b` thats why I was getting the error, I initialized `valcol` earlier I forgot to mention it here.

Comment: @Gajju simoco's right, there are 0 and both rows and columns in Excel are 1 based. So Cells(0,0) always fails.

Answer (score 2):

In your "fun" Function, you declare wrk to be a worksheet, but you then use it inside quotation marks :

```
ah = Sheets("wrk").Cells(b, varcol - 1)
```

Instead, try replacing that last line with :

```
ah = wrk.Cells(b, varcol - 1)
```